# how to assign doc.topMargin for different pages using reportlab simpledoctemplate

Tags: python, reportlab

I'm generating a PDF but I'm not able to give different different topmargins to different pages.

Is there any method or any way to solve this problem?

```
response = HttpResponse(mimetype='application/pdf')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachments;filename='aa.pdf'
doc = SimpleDocTemplate(response)
elements = []
table_data = [["Cash Management -"],
              ["individuelle Kond-"],
              ["Cash Mas -"],
              ["Terms and Condppe"],
              ]
table_dimension = Table(table_data, colWidths=[19.8 * cm], rowHeights=(.23*inch))
table_dimension.setStyle(TableStyle([
                          ('BACKGROUND',(0,0),(0,3),'0x2E8B57'),
                          ('TEXTCOLOR',(0,0),(0,3),'0xFFFFFF'),
                          ('FONT', (0,0), (0,3), 'Times-Italic'),
                          ('ALIGN',(0,0),(0,3),'CENTER'),
                          ("VALIGN",(0,2),(0,2),"BOTTOM"),
                          ('FONTSIZE',(0,0),(0,1),14)
                ]))
elements.append(table_dimension)
doc.topMargin=.13* inch
doc.build(elements)
return response
```

Now on all the pages the top margin remains tha same but I want different different margins on each page.

Answer (score 6):

A `DocTemplate` class (like `SimpleDocTemplate`) is filled with `PageTemplate`'s which are then filled with `Frame`'s which then are filled with `Flowable`'s (like your `Table`). `SimpleDocTemplate` (as the name suggests) simplifies things buy providing you with the most basic setup: a `DocTemplate` which already has a `PageTemplate` and a basic `Frame` which just has to be filled with `Flowable`'s. So here's the problem: the `DocTemplate` margins are fixed for the whole document which by the way makes sense. You want to adjust the margins of your `Frame`'s! For this you can either try to get a handle on the currently used frame or start using the more elaborate `BaseDocTemplate` and define your own `PageTemplate`'s and `Frame`'s.  I would suggest that you read the corresponding pages in the [reportlab user guide](http://www.reportlab.com/docs/reportlab-userguide.pdf%E2%80%8E) under chapter 5 and search for an `BaseDocTemplate` example which shows the generation of `Frame`'s and `PageTemplate`'s.

Another option would be not to use the margins directly. You could use `Spacer()` to add vertical space and the colWidths of your table to adjust the horizontal width but this isn't really fun to do. `SimpleDocTemplate` adds the `PageTemplates` and `Frames` inside the build function, so we can't modify them before that. If you need a more extensive example, you need to post more code so i can see what you really want, because your code produces only one page.

**UPDATE**

Here is an example on how to use the Frame-size yo adjust the margins on different pages. One could also adjust the size of the PageTemplates. I think you should be able to understand the code, but again: thie is BaseDocTemplate, not SimpleDocTemplate. If you have a table on the first page which spans over the first page, you don't need to add the `PageBreak()`, but the `NextPageTemplate()` is mandatory!

```
"""
Example how to adjust the Frame-size in a BaseDocTemplate
"""
from reportlab.platypus import BaseDocTemplate, Frame, Paragraph, NextPageTemplate, PageBreak, PageTemplate
from reportlab.lib.units import inch
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet

def on_first_page(canvas,doc):
    canvas.saveState()
    canvas.setFont('Times-Roman',19)
    canvas.drawString(inch, 0.75 * inch, "Page %d" % doc.page)
    canvas.restoreState()

def on_remaining_pages(canvas,doc):
    canvas.saveState()
    canvas.setFont('Times-Roman',9)
    canvas.drawString(inch, 0.75 * inch, "Page %d" % doc.page)
    canvas.restoreState()

# creation of the BaseDocTempalte. showBoundary=0 to hide the debug borders
doc = BaseDocTemplate('basedoc.pdf',showBoundary=1)

# create the frames. Here you can adjust the margins
frame_first_page = Frame(doc.leftMargin, doc.bottomMargin, doc.width, doc.height, id='first')
frame_remaining_pages = Frame(doc.leftMargin + 1*inch, doc.bottomMargin + 1*inch, doc.width - 2*inch, doc.height - 2*inch, id='remaining')

# add the PageTempaltes to the BaseDocTemplate. You can also modify those to adjust the margin if you need more control over the Frames.
doc.addPageTemplates([PageTemplate(id='first_page',frames=frame_first_page, onPage=on_first_page),
                      PageTemplate(id='remaining_pages',frames=frame_remaining_pages, onPage=on_remaining_pages),
                      ])

styles=getSampleStyleSheet()
# start the story...
Elements=[]

Elements.append(Paragraph("Frame first page!",styles['Normal']))
Elements.append(NextPageTemplate('remaining_pages'))  #This will load the next PageTemplate with the adjusted Frame. 
Elements.append(PageBreak()) # This will force a page break so you are guarented to get the next PageTemplate/Frame

Elements.append(Paragraph("Frame remaining pages!,  "*500,styles['Normal']))

#start the construction of the pdf
doc.build(Elements)
```

Comment: thanks fookatchu but is there any way using the same doc template except basedoctemplate

Comment: hello fookatchu, i am explaining you my code: 1) i create 3 tables and store or insert the data into the elements array..2)I am using the two headers one header for page 1 and the other header for remaining pages 3)and i add row dynamically in the table 4)i set one doc.topmargin and it is same for all but i want it different for the first page 5) My code is very big thats why i am not posting ,if you donot get it then tell me,i will post after minimising it....thanks in advance

Comment: @user2501134 : This answer should be marked as correct. It definitely solve your problem.